# Create a multiple dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

We can create a dropdown dynamically using jquery in the following fashion

```
var color = $('<select />', {
                                         'class'  : 'relation-select',
                                         'id'     : 'color_' + j,
                                         'name'   : 'color[]'


});
```

I want to create a drop down having this HTML:

```
<select name="collection_id[]" id="collection_id" multiple data-rel="chosen">
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('<select />', {
    'id': 'collection_id',
    'multiple': true,
    'name': 'collection_id[]'
}).attr('data-rel', 'chosen');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/62mxf/).

Result (as displayed in the demo's console):

```
<select id="collection_id" multiple="multiple" name="collection_id[]"
    data-rel="chosen"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create element directly by passing string to jQuery selection. Check below code and [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ESu8/1/)

```
HTML:

<div id="hello"></div>

JS:
var a = $('<select name="collection_id[]" id="collection_id" multiple data-rel="chosen"></select>')

$("#hello").append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
var color = $('<select />', {
    'class'  : 'relation-select',
    'id'     : 'color_' + j,
    'name'   : 'color[]',
    'multiple' : 1,
    'data-rel' : 'chosen'
})
```